# Design choice for automatically kicking off an ASP.NET WebForm app that performs a simple task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, webforms

I've been tasked with enhancing a basic C# ASP.NET WebForm app that performs a simple sync action.

Users log in, click a button, and sync is executed.

What I'd like to do now - ideally - is allow them to log in and set an interval (hourly, daily, etc..) through the app by which this sync will occur automatically without them having to subsequently log in to manually "pull the lever".

I'm curious what would be the recommended design path(s) to implement this without TOO much restructuring (ex extricating all the sync code and creating a standalone web service).

All ideas/thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: sync what? Also *without TOO much restructuring* what's too much? Also what do you plan on using for your scheduling?

Comment: Didn't think it mattered.  It shuffles data between two databases.

As far as scheduling I envision having to create a separate web service to ping my app on an interval equal to the lowest sync interval I make available to the user.  It'll scan the database to check for scheduled syncs and run any that are at that given time.

The app utilizes native ASP user management.  Not sure how unattended authentication will work, if ASP has utilities in place to aid in functionality like this and/or if this approach is even viable.

Comment: I asked because synch could mean a lot of things. But you've clarified it. As for scheduling anything running on Web server I recommend against it since web stuff tends to be request based. A result of this is that there's an expectation that if your app is idle for 20 minutes its safe to shut it down. [See Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to keep it completely in the database backend. For example if this is SQL Server - just create a scheduled job - and you can control the settings of the job from ASP.NET front end.

If this is not an option - next best thing is a Windows Service. You ASP.NET front end saves the setting for the sync into DB and service reads those settings and acts accordingly.